# The dualising sheaf of a nodal curve by Grothendieck duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, serre-duality

I am trying to use Grothendieck duality ([Duality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AU3)) to prove that the dualising sheaf $\omega_X$ of a nodal curve $X$ can be described as the pushforward sheaf of the sheaf of differential forms on the normalization $\widetilde{X}$ with at most simple poles on the preimages of singularities such that the sum of their residues over the preimages of any singular point is zero([eg, here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312494/why-is-this-the-dualising-sheaf-of-a-singular-curve)), but I met some difficulties as I now explain.

So assume I can embed $f:X\rightarrow P^2$, then by (4) of [Duality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AU3) we have $\omega_X^{\bullet}=f^{!}\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet}$. Assume further that $X$ is cut out by a single equation so that it is a complete intersection, by (8) of [Duality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AU3) we have $f^{!}\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet}=Lf^{*}(\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet})\otimes_{O_X}O_{P^2}(X)[-1]$, where $Lf^{*}$ is the derived pullback.

Now since $\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet}=\Omega^2_{P^2}[2]$ is an actual invertible sheaf sitting in degree 2, I assume I can regard it as *K-flat*, in a sense of ([K-flat](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06Y7)), and $Lf^{*}(\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet})=f^*(\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet})$.

Now my question is: how to describe the sheaf $f^*(\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet})$ when $X$ is not smooth(especially, how to describe it at the singular points), and how can I prove that $Lf^{*}(\omega_{P^2}^{\bullet})\otimes_{O_X}O_{P^2}(X)[-1]$ is actually the same sheaf with the sheaf I described in the first paragraph?

Any comments or helps are welcome!

Comment: To relate dualizing complexes/sheaves to modules of differentials, the stacks project isn't the right thing to look at (it avoids relating the two). I kindly suggest looking at books and papers by Hartshorne, Lipman, Kleiman, and others.

Comment: @Johan $f*\Omega_{P^2}$ doesn’t look like a complicated sheaf, I believe someone know how to describe it. I think it would be really nice if we can use Grothendieck duality to compute X’s dualising sheaf.

Comment: @YuanYang I don't think Johan is disagreeing. He is the primary author of the source you have cited numerous times, and is simply pointing out that it's particular exposition will not help you with this calculation.

Comment: @Johan Thank you very much for your replies-I have all my respect to the pages that you’ve made on stacks project. I just remembered that someone seems to be successfully using this page to compute the dualising complex of some other singular varieties in some paper... Anyway, I will wait for some more time