# Dualising sheaf of a nodal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, serre-duality

Let $X$ be a projective nodal curve. Why is the dualizing sheaf of $X$ isomorphic to the log-cotangent bundle of $X$?

Comment: Welcome to MO. Your question seems a possible duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312494/why-is-this-the-dualising-sheaf-of-a-singular-curve

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi How?

Comment: The answer to your question is, essentially: pass to the normalization $\tilde{X}$ of $X$, compute the dualizing sheaf of $\tilde{X}$ and then deduce the form of the dualizing sheaf of $X$ by using the Residue Theorem. This is explained in the question I linked, and in the answer and in the comments you can also find some standard references.